# I want to load all image containing folders from external storage and internal storage but do the code but not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-file

I want to make gallery app so I want to load images from folders but its not working its not giving any output and sometimes gives output but taking so much time.
Any help for get image from both storage and how to load it fast problems I am facing.
Please help

```
void  additemtolist(String directoryPath )
{


    File filex=new File(directoryPath);

    if(filex.isDirectory()&&!filex.getName().endsWith(".dir")&& !filex.getName().startsWith(".") )
    {
        File[] files = new File(directoryPath).listFiles(new ImageFileFilter());
        if (files.length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (isdirectory(files[i]) == true && !files[i].getName().endsWith(".dir")&& !files[i].getName().startsWith("."))
                {
                    if (getimagefolder(files[i])==true)
                    {
                        File srta[] = files[i].listFiles();
                        Random random = new Random();
                        int num = random.nextInt(srta.length);
                        Bitmap image = BitmapHelper.decodeBitmapFromFile(srta[num].getAbsolutePath(),
                                50,
                                50);

                        gridItems.add(new GridViewItem(files[i].getParentFile().getAbsolutePath(), true, image, files[i].getName(), files[i].getAbsolutePath().toString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        additemtolist(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                     /* if(isImageFile(files[i].getAbsolutePath()))
                      {


                          //Random random = new Random();
                         // int num = random.nextInt(srta.length);
                          Bitmap image = BitmapHelper.decodeBitmapFromFile(files[i].getAbsolutePath(),
                                  50,
                                  50);

                          gridItems.add(new GridViewItem(files[i].getParentFile().getAbsolutePath(), true, image, files[i].getName(), files[i].getAbsolutePath().toString()));
                      }*/
                }


            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: `void additemtolist(String directoryPath )`. Show the value for directoryPath when you call the function.

Comment: Please format your code so we dont have to scroll horizontally. You are asking too uch of us now. And from your self!

Comment: `getimagefolder(` What does that function?

Comment: getimage folder gives is file contains image or not